# Permalinks stopped working - NO update, mod_rewrite enabled, .htaccess not touched

Tags: permalinks, 404-error

At first, my permalinks and all worked.
My permalinks were in `/year/month/post/` format.
Today I found out when I try to open an *Anspress* question, I get a 404. (that worked too, last time I checked) 
Then I read somewhere I need permalink format of `/postname/` to display Anspress questions.

So I changed it to `/postname/`. Now nothing except `index.php?p=xyz` is working. All links to pages throw a 404. I tried changing back to `/year/month/post/` , but that did not help. Tried going to *Permalinks* and clicking *"Save settings"*, but that did not help either. Tried `a2enmod rewrite` (although it has worked before), no help.

I have no idea. It worked 30 minutes ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. Maybe an Apache update or something did this to me.

I changed `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` for the `/var/www` folder.

Answer (score 0):

i have also faced such kinds of problem when i upload the project to server and for fixed this i have followed below steps :

1. change permalink and save it again. if code display below then replace with that code
2. enable rewrite_mode and for doing this is have followed the steps from this article : `https://anandnayi.wordpress.com/2015/07/04/404-not-found-apache-centos/`